# Why do "This question already has an answer here" links appear slightly lower than "Possible Duplicate" links in duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, bug, duplicate-questions, design

If you were to look really closely at duplicate questions, you find that the header in newer duplicates with "This question already has an answer here" (or "This question is an exact duplicate of") is slightly lower than the old "Possible Duplicate" links in older questions. Examples (use the vote buttons as reference points):

- An older question:
  [image]
- A newer question:
  [image]

Is this a design bug?