# Does the RemoveDeadQuestions directive apply to meta?

Tags: support, meta, deleted-questions, per-site-meta

Under the RemoveDeadQuestions directive, any unanswered questions with a score less than 0 get [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/172266) by the Community ♦ user.  The RemoveAbandonedQuestions [does not run on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304244/172266), but does the RemoveDeadQuestions apply on MSE and on per-site metas?  On meta, downvoting may simply indicate disagreement, but a proposal that people disagree with may still have value to retain, compared to a question that people consider a bad one.

Comment: Note that they are not deleted by the community, they are deleted by [Community ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). This user is so notorious that they were recently [Suspended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377009/community-user-got-suspended-in-teams) elsewhere on the network.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Right, I know.  My formulation was sloppy.  Corrected now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting Shog9 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304300):

> This only applies to the RemoveAbandonedQuestions check; **all other** automated question deletion routines documented on that page run on both main and meta sites.

So yes, RemoveDeadQuestions runs on Meta, and here's a live example:

> [image: aaa]